# Get push notification while App in foreground iOS 14 and above

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-push-notification, foregroundnotification, push-notification-ios

I have implemented ios push notification using

- `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios`
- `react-native-push-notification`.

`foreground` notification not working (`banner/alert`) also `onNotification` is not getting called for remote notification.

On `iOS 14` it was displaying `banner/alert` notification , after device update, it is not working.

Expected changes in `AppDelegate` file at below function

```html
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  NSLog( @"Sagar_foreground" );

  if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionList | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBanner | UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
  } else {
// Fallback on earlier versions
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);

  }
}
```

Replacing below snippet helped me to call `onNotification` but its getting called in loop.

```html
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
  //Foreground
  NSLog(@"APP_PUSH from foreground %@", userInfo);

  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:^void (UIBackgroundFetchResult result){}];
  
  if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBanner | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
  } else {
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
  }
```